# python: count number of items inside parent list

Tags: python, list, iteration

Let's say I have the following lists:

```
yrs = [2016, 2017]
months = [['June'], ['January', 'February']]
names = [[['John', 'Mike']], [['Sara'], ['Steph', 'James']]]
```

I want to count the number of names associated with each year. So for the example above I would get 2 names for 2016 and 3 names for 2017. So I guess I need a way to flatten the lists when I iterate over each year.

```
for yr_index in range(len(names)):
    print yrs[yr_index], '-->', names[yr_index]

# 2016 --> [['John', 'Mike']]
# 2017 --> [['Sara'], ['Steph', 'James']]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more pls? Am not sure i got what you meant by count number of items inside Parent list. You want to know whats the length of `yrs`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of names for each year, or the flat list of names associated with each year as follows:

```
yrs = [2016, 2017]
months = [['June'], ['January', 'February']]
names = [[['John', 'Mike']], [['Sara'], ['Steph', 'James']]]

for yr_index in range(len(names)):
    # print the number of names for each year
    print yrs[yr_index], '-->', len([item for sublist in names[yr_index] for item in sublist])

    # print the names for each year
    print yrs[yr_index], '-->', [item for sublist in names[yr_index] for item in sublist]
```

This prints:

```
2016 --> 2
2016 --> ['John', 'Mike']
2017 --> 3
2017 --> ['Sara', 'Steph', 'James']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to play with the `zip` function e.g.

```
>>> list(zip(yrs, months, names))
[(2016, ['June'], [['John', 'Mike']]), (2017, ['January', 'February'], [['Sara'], ['Steph', 'James']])]
```

Now you can stick in this a loop and zip again:

```
>>> for yr, yr_months, yr_names in zip(yrs, months, names):
...     for month, month_names in zip(yr_months, yr_names):
...         print(yr, month, month_names)
... 
2016 June ['John', 'Mike']
2017 January ['Sara']
2017 February ['Steph', 'James']
```

Alternatively (but not as clear in my opinion), use `enumerate` (I'll leave the inner loop as an exercise):

```
>>> for yr_index, yr in enumerate(yrs):
...     print(yr, months[yr_index])
... 
2016 ['June']
2017 ['January', 'February']
```

You're probably aware that `len(my_list)` gives the number of items in a list. You could use the above with a loop counter to count the number of names in each year. Alternatively, combine the outer loop with a generator comprehension and the `sum` function to get the number of items in a list of lists:

```
>>> x = [[1,2], [3, 4]]
>>> sum(len(sub_list) for sub_list in x)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it in a data structure and not just to print:

```
outcome = {}

for year_index, year in enumerate(yrs):
    outcome[str(year)] = names[year_index]

print(outcome)

# {'2017': [['Sara'], ['Steph', 'James']], '2016': [['John', 'Mike']]}
```

Otherwise:

```
for year_index, year in enumerate(yrs):
    print('{0} --> {1}'.format(str(year), names[year_index]))

# 2016 --> [['John', 'Mike']]
# 2017 --> [['Sara'], ['Steph', 'James']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the number in each year, this will work:

```
result = {}
for index, year in enumerate(yrs):
    result[year] = sum([len(sublist) for sublist in names[index]])

>>> result
{2016: 2, 2017: 3}
```

Short and simple.